# Guava CheckedFuture<X,Y> map to CheckedFuture <Z,Y> without blocking

Tags: java, guava, future

I have recently been faced with Guava and its Asynchronous Future API.

I have a method with a similar declaration as this one bellow:

`CheckedFuture<X, Y> update(final X entry)`

which at some point might call a method with the following signature:

`CheckedFuture<Boolean, Y> delete(final X entry)`

What I have been looking at and didn't found is a way to map the result from the call to `delete` be mapped to `CheckedFuture<X, Y>` which is the return type of `update`.

*Has anyone been able to do it without blocking the whole computation at some point by calling `delete(entry).checkedGet()`?*

Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** I know the Guava javadocs recommend the avoidance of CheckedFutures, but atm this is how the API is built and it's impractical to rebuild it (not meaning I'm not looking forward to it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Futures#transform`

```
CheckedFuture<X, Y> update(final X entry) {
    CheckedFuture<Boolean, Y> f = delete(entry);
    ListenableFuture<X> tr = Futures.transform(f, (Function<Boolean, X>) input -> entry);
    return Futures.makeChecked(tr, input -> (Y) input.getCause());
}

CheckedFuture<Boolean, Y> delete(final X entry) {
    return Futures.immediateFailedCheckedFuture(new Y());
}
```